# Hibernate Entitymanager - what does it mean by "deprecated - use hibernate-core instead"?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was following a hibernate jpa tutorial, and I needed to use the entitymanager. But when I checked the mvnrepository, it said "deprecated - use hibernate-core instead". And apparently, my application would not work without hibernate-entitymanager as a dependency (and it would not work with both hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager as dependencies).

Can someone help explain why it's "deprecated"?
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager

Comment: That means you should use this as dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core

Comment: In your case it seems that you should still use hibernate-entitymanager.
At the time of writing, hibernate's doc says:
«for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core»
http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that in new version of Hibernate `hibernate-entitymanager` component is deprecated and all functionality that you need, you can get from `hibernate-core` component. Link to last version of `hibernate-core` component in Maven Central Repository [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-core%7C5.2.1.Final%7Cjar). Add this dependency to your *pom.xml* file.

Comment: I see now, I tried removing hibernate-entitymanager before but forgot to use the latest version of hibernate-core. That's why it didn't work, and I was confused. It works fine after updating.